# Finding the shortest path in a cyclical graph using Dijkstra

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have a cyclical directed graph. Below is the representation of the graph as a python dict

```
graph = {
          'A': {'B': 5, 'D': 5, 'E': 7 },
          'B': {'C': 4},
          'C': {'D': 8, 'E': 2},
          'D': {'C': 8, 'E':  6},
          'E': {'B': 3}
        }
```

I have wrote a simple implementation of a Dijkstra's shortest path. Which seems to work for given two points. Below is my implementation.

```
def shortestpath(self, start, end, visited=[],distances={},predecessors={}):
        # initialize a big number
        maxint = 10000 

        if start==end:
            path=[]
            while end != None:
                path.append(end)
                end=predecessors.get(end, None)
            return distances[start], path[::-1]

        # detect if it's the first time through, set current distance to zero
        if not visited: distances[start]=0
        # process neighbors as per algorithm, keep track of predecessors
        for neighbor in self.graph[start]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                neighbordist = distances.get(neighbor,maxint)
                tentativedist = distances[start] + self.graph[start][neighbor]
                if tentativedist < neighbordist:
                    distances[neighbor] = tentativedist
                    predecessors[neighbor]=start

        # neighbors processed, now mark the current node as visited
        visited.append(start)
        # finds the closest unvisited node to the start
        unvisiteds = dict((k, distances.get(k,maxint)) for k in self.graph if k not in visited)
        closestnode = min(unvisiteds, key=unvisiteds.get)
        # now we can take the closest node and recurse, making it current
        return self.shortestpath(closestnode,end,visited,distances,predecessors)
```

now this simple implementation seems to work. For example if I do somthing like this

```
shortestpath('A', 'C')
```

it will give me the path and shortest weight

> (9, ['A', 'B', 'C'])

in this case.
However, whenever I `shortestpath('B', 'B')` the program will break.
Now there is a shortest path from `B to B` since it is a cyclic graph the path is B-C-E-B. I just don't know how to check for that and modify the Dijktra's algorithm accordingly to have it check for cyclic cases like this one. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the shortest distance from `B` to `B` is zero, since you are already there. If you want to find the cyclic distance, the simplest solution is probably to add a new virtual node `Bs` which have all the same outbound edges as `B`. Then all you have to do, is to find the shortest path from `Bs` to `B`. I imagine that more general solutions are also available, e.g., where you modify the algorithm to not allow a zero total distance.

Comment: Also, you should replace the `visited` list by a set, to reduce the asymptotic run time, as when the list of visited nodes grows, it will take too long to identify nodes not in the visted list (linear time, which will make the whole algorithm `> O(n^2)`.

Comment: The standard approach to this is checking whether the start node is a goal node, i.e. if start == end then there is no path to return. Why then are you checking instead if self == end?

Comment: because it is a cyclic graph.